# Materialize css modal open on page load with fixed nav - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, overlay, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS and have several modals on my site. Some of them I want to open on loading a particular new page. Everything was working and then I switched to a fixed `nav` and all of a sudden the open commands aren't working.

It seems that the function is working but it is not changing the modal to `display: block` so it acts as if it is open, but nothing is visible and the `body` `overlay` has been turned on so that you can not scroll.

I have tried numerous different ways to implement the `modal.open();` and from what I can tell it is that something is getting in the way of the function and overriding some of the styles.

I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

```
<body>

<!--       NAVIGATION       --->

<header>
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s7 m2 valign-wrapper">
                    <a class="modal-trigger" href="#login"><img src="/images/Logo.png" alt="" class="loginLogo"></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="col s5 m3 offset-m7 valign-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li><button id="successBtn" data-target="signUpSuccess" class="btn btn-signUp btn-success modal-trigger">Sign up</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Modal Structure -->

<div id="signUpSuccess" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h4>You're signed up!</h4>
                <p>We will notify you soon.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signUpSuccess").modal();
    $("#signUpSuccess").modal("open");
});
```

To reiterate - The modals are still working when clicked but the `#signUpSuccess` modal is not opening on load and it was working prior to changing to `navbar-fixed`.

Materialize CSS: https://materializecss.com/modals.html

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: can you please try $("#successBtn).trigger("click") or $("#successBtn).click()  in  document.ready function?

Comment: @MohanPrajapati I did try triggering the button and the same thing happened. That is why I am at a loss of how to fix it.

Comment: can you provide a working code snippet so we can see the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `instance.open()`.

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();
        });

</script>
```

Check documentation [Materialize Modals](https://materializecss.com/modals.html), there are many options available for animations. You should also try using vanilla JS because jQuery is no longer a dependency.

Comment: This fixed the open problem. But I have several modals. I want certain ones to open on load when from a certain processing page. For instance, there is a "Contact Us" modal in the footer that sends an email. It is processed on the same page and when it is finished I want the modal to open with a "Thank you message"

Comment: But not open automatically every time - only if someone has used the "Contact Us" form.

Comment: Open "Thank You message" modal after button click right?

Comment: Yes. I ended up changing `document.querySelector('.modal');` to `document.querySelector('.contactSuccess');` and then have `.contactSuccess` be the first `modal` populated only if the email processing is successful. So if it's not populated, nothing comes up. I'm sure there is a better way to go about it, but at least it is working. Thank you!